# Renaming a project results in compiler error

Tags: ios, xcode

I was just required to rename project. The actual rename was done within seconds, by renaming the project name. However XCode was not able to compile my project anymore after the rename. It claimed for missing files after that. 
Is that the cruel reality, that in 2012 it is not possible to simply rename a project in XCode and rely on it? What I did, is creating a new project from scratch and imported all my files. Took me only about 10 minutes, however I had to be very careful not to forget any compiler settings or anything else. 
But from a versioning standpoint this is an absolute nightmare. Has anyone a "real" solution for the renaming issue?

BTW: I tried to rename the files which the compiler claimed are missing manually but also without success, why I came up with the new project approach.

Comment: Did you use the Xcode rename function? Or did you manually rename some files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give [Rename Xcode Project](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/17683/rename-xcode-project) a try. It will iterate through your project files and rename the necessary objects in your project. Seems to work well with Xcode 4.2 as well.

Comment: Nice. Although it's sad we need an app to do what should be such a simple task. :(

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more.

Comment: What I did was renaming by clicking on the project name and confirmed the changes which XCode detected (Release 4.3). I may try that app next time. But as it was said, not really understandable, that this does not work out of the box, especially as the feature actually is available. Anyway, thanks for the hint.